# python doesn't import module

Tags: python, module

I need to import a module named array_queue in python. I've checked and if I don't use it an alert saying "array_queue imported but unused". However if I use it and run the program this comes back:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'array_queue'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tricky to answer without code. However a few questions/answers that might help you solve this.

Is "array_queue" a module you wrote yourself? I couldn't find a module that is called that. All I could find that was remotely similar was [this file](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/python/43stack/arrayqueue.py.html).

Could it be that you either didn't install the module properly (pip install MODULE_NAME in your terminal) or that this module might be named wrong? Double check to make sure such a module exists with the name "array_queue". I don't think Python native build-ins / Python library has such a module.

I don't mean to impose but I of course don't know your level. In case you are unsure about modules please check [this python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html).

Comment: "array_queue" is indeed a module written by me, sorry for not mentioning that before, it probably led you to confusion. I actually had been using it these past few days and it worked perfectly but today I was going to continue with the code I'm working on and when I run the program it couldn't import it and I don't know what I did.